# Read insert statements from text file

Tags: mysql, linux

Good day All,

I have a 1000 text files that each contain 1000 insert into statements. What is the most efficient way to read and execute each insert statement into a MySQL DB table?

Thanks for any assistance here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this two ways.

Use the `mysql` client [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163694/how-do-you-use-mysqls-source-command-to-import-large-files-in-windows) command.

mysql> `SOURCE mysql_stuff.txt` **or** `mysql> \. mysql_stuff.txt`

or, you can use the [`mysql` client from the shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-batch-commands.html).

$> `mysql -u my_user -pmy_password my_schema < mysql_stuff.txt`

**Note** - no space between -p and the actual password. If you don't put in the password, you will be prompted for it, **but** you must include the `-p` or else the client will throw an error.

Now, if you have multiple files and you wish to go through them and execute each one, then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-directory).

You could use `sed`, `awk` and `grep` in inventive ways to create SQL text files with a 1000 lines, each with a different file name - you could start with (in the directory containing your SQL files).

`ls --format single-column > mysql_stuff.txt` (bash or cygwin)

and then add SOURCE (+ space) to the beginning of each line

`sed -i -e 's/^/SOURCE /' mysql_stuff.txt`

- 1) -e not strictly necessary in this case, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33159/99494). It's used
  in the case where one wishes to run multiple commands at once.
- 2) -i means perform the edit "inplace" - no new file is created. If you're not sure of your regular expressions (either search and/or replace), then backup your file.
- 3) the circumflex (^) is part of the regular expression search pattern. It means start the replace at the beginning of the line.

and then run `SOURCE mysql_stuff.txt` from the mysql client and it will go through the file executing each line. Oh, yes, don't forget to add a semi-colon ; to the end of each line also.

`sed -i -e 's/$/;/' mysql_stuff.txt`

- the $ means perform the substitution at the end of the line.

Comment: Nice way to manage `sed`.

Comment: Thanks - I always prefer to run scripts as SOURCE blah.sql rather than from the prompt - you get more informative errors that way (sometimes!).